# Difference-in-difference: case when parallel trends assumption is met but difference in levels lead to misleading treatment effect

Tags: causality, difference-in-difference

I'm working on a diff-in-diffs analysis to look at the effect of a treatment on performance on standardized test. The treatment affected Hispanic but not white students, so I'm using white students as a control. Specifically, I want to study the raw scores obtained on the test and the passing rate. To give an example of the problem I'm facing:

- Let’s say in the 5-years preceding treatment, raw scores for both groups had parallel trends but the average score for white students was 10 points higher. Further, both groups had a 100% passing rate.
- In the post-treatment period, both groups saw their scores decrease by 10 points (white students still scoring 10 points higher)
- Because Hispanic students already had lower scores than their white counterparts, this drop in scores was enough to put many of them below the passing rate threshold. The same was not true for the higher-performing white students.

If I only looked at passing rates, I'd see a drop for Hispanic students but not white students and wrongfully attribute it to the effects of the treatment. I'm attaching graphs showing the above scenario.

[image: Raw scores]
[image: Passing rates]

My question is: is there a way to deal with this in the analysis?

Comment: You're observing a drop in "pass rates" because you've redefined your dependent variable as pass/fail. I have a few questions before I can even attempt a response. First, does your treatment begin in year 3? Second, was the treatment directed at Hispanic students? Third, the flat line for White students is a bit misleading. Do 100 percent of Whites students pass this exam? If you're going with pass rates, then you should look at the *proportions* over time. You can accomplish this with a generalized linear model, but that introduces a whole new set of problems in this setting.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry about the lack of clarity. I simulated data for the example, so I'll answer accordingly. 1) Treatment does begin in year 3; 2) Treatment was directed at Hispanic students; 3) In this data, I did have 100% of white students pass the exam, but we can think of a similar example with different passing rates.

Comment: Similar example with different pass rates, and using just two time periods (pre and post). Pre treatment, 90 white students (ws) got a score of 90 pts and 10 ws got score of 60 pts. Since threshold for passing is 61pts, ws had a 90% pass rate. Post-treatment, everyone experienced a 20 pt drop (90 students with 70 pts and 10 with 40 pts). Hispanic students all score 20 pts under their white counterparts, so the higher scoring hispanic students go from 70 pts in the pre-trestment to 50 pts in post. This means the passing rate for Hispanic but not White students decreases.